# href location doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

on the header of my site http://thetrashedvintage.com/ I use:

```
<div class="collections" onclick="location.href='http://thetrashedvintage.com/wool-collection';" style="cursor: pointer;">
                <img src="http://www.thetrashedvintage.com/collections.jpg" alt="Collections" />
                </div>
```

for make the div clickable, but when I click it redirects somewhere else, when I click on Collections, it redirects me to Login, the next div, any ideas of what I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It works well for me http://jsfiddle.net/fizerkhan/F9rJE/

Comment: Login is overlapping the Collections div

Comment: Is there any reason why using a `DIV` and `onclick` instead of a link?

Comment: The CSS settings for these divs ('collections' and 'login', for example) form heavily overlapping rectangles with absolute settings. So it's quite confused I think. As @kei pointed out, the 'login' overlaps (and is in front of) the 'collections'. Are you familiar with the browsers debug "inspection" capability? It comes in handy for spotting this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Collections div is being overlapped by your Login div

To fix this,

change your CSS from

```css
div.login {
  width: 50%;
  right: -130px;
}
```

to

```css
div.login {
  /*width: 50%; <-- REMOVE THIS */
  right: 115px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting your div in an a like this

```
<a href="location where your stuff is"><div class="collections" style="cursor: pointer;"> <img src="http://www.thetrashedvintage.com/collections.jpg" alt="Collections" />
</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong CSS. If you have FireFox use Inspector, press Ctrl+Shift+C and goto with mouse on login and see margins div login (overlap collections) and goto more left there is margin collection. CSS with fixed position is bad idea.

Sorry for my funny english.